# API docs for previous versions?

Tags: openlayers-3

Are the API docs for previous versions online anywhere? The links I find are all to "latest" but I'd like to access API docs for 3.18 and 3.20.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure they are see the following links: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.18.0/apidoc/ and http://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.0/apidoc/

Comment: These links are broken now and go to 404 pages.

Comment: Yes the older versions got removed because of disk space issues in gh-pages

Comment: This answer is no longer valid, I can confirm a 404 also.